# How to call a model method from rails view through a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Please bear with me. I went through similar questions here but my requirement is quiet different.

I have a model called **RideLaterRequest**. In the app I am allowing the user to create a record on this model. And currently once the record is saved a notification is being sent to a android app. The logic is as follows:

**ride_later_request.rb**

```
class RideLaterRequest < ActiveRecord::Base

   after_save :send_notif #run send_notif method once the record is saved.

   def send_notif
      RideLaterRequestHandler.ride_later_request_created(self)
   end

end
```

The above method actually calls another class method (the earlier developer defined a method in a separate class)

```
class RideLaterRequestHandler
    def self.ride_later_request_created(ride_later_request)
      #####................####
    end
end
```

So once this method executes a notification is being sent to the android app.

Now I am trying to stop this automated system. And handle this flow manually by adding a button in view file.

First I stopped the automated notification by commenting `after_save :send_notif` in the **ride_later_request.rb** file. So now there are no notifications being sent once a new record is saved on that model.

In a view file I am displaying the records of **RideLaterRequest** model as follows:

**admin_reports_controller.rb**

```
class AdminReportsController < ApplicationController

  def trip_report
   @ride_later_request = RideLaterRequest.all
  end

end
```

**trip_report.html.erb**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Trip ID</th>
      <th>Send Notification</th>
   </tr>
   <% @ride_later_requests.each do |trip_report| %>
   <tr>
      <td><%= trip_report.planned_start_time.to_date%></td>
      <td><%= trip_report.id%></td>
      <td>
       <%= button_to "Send Notification", #In normal case I would have added a path to the controller method to Send notification here %> 
      </td>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

As you can see I am trying add a button action where it sends the notification. The only thing I am trying to do here is, earlier the notifications were being sent once a new `ride_later_request` row was created. Now I am stopping that and trying to do it manually on a already saved record by adding a button. My question is is how can I call `def send_notif` model method that I have explained above in the beginning on this button that I am trying to give ?

I know this is app specific question but I have tried my best to make it rails specific by explaining it, I guess. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand your question correctly. You already know that you `would add a path to controller method to Send notification`. So you just answered yourself.

Comment: @yeuem1vannam Yes. I would have if the method was in controller. But its a model method that I need to add a path to. So how can I call that `send_notif` method from view ?

Comment: Did you check out my answer? You don't call methods from a rendered view. Rendered views submit requests to controllers (roughly) which resolve via routes to controller actions. Then, controllers take it from there.

Comment: @user3576036 When you see the HTML ( the button ) on your browser, there is no models / controllers, just client / server. So if your business has to be done on the server ( the `send_notif` ) then you have to make a request from your client to server. That being said, you are misunderstanding about the MVC.

Comment: I think I am asking the question wrong way. I know the controller makes a call to the model. But inorder to do that I need to add a path to that method in controller right ? Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a `send_notification` action on your `RideLaterRequestController` and then (in `routes.rb`) setting up a `send_nofication_ride_later_request` path. Perhaps something like:

```
resources :ride_later_requests do 
  member do 
    post :send_nofication
  end
end
```

Which yields:

```
send_nofication_ride_later_request POST   /ride_later_requests/:id/send_nofication(.:format)   ride_later_requests#send_nofication
                                   POST   /ride_later_requests(.:format)                       ride_later_requests#create
               ride_later_requests GET    /ride_later_requests(.:format)                       ride_later_requests#index
            new_ride_later_request GET    /ride_later_requests/new(.:format)                   ride_later_requests#new
           edit_ride_later_request GET    /ride_later_requests/:id/edit(.:format)              ride_later_requests#edit
                ride_later_request GET    /ride_later_requests/:id(.:format)                   ride_later_requests#show
                                   PATCH  /ride_later_requests/:id(.:format)                   ride_later_requests#update
                                   PUT    /ride_later_requests/:id(.:format)                   ride_later_requests#update
                                   DELETE /ride_later_requests/:id(.:format)                   ride_later_requests#destroy
```

Then do something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Send Notification', send_nofication_ride_later_request_path(trip_report), method: :post %>
```

You can dress that link to look like a button.

Then, in your `RideLaterRequestController`, something like:

```
class RideLaterRequestController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def send_notification
    @ride_later_request = RideLaterRequest.find_by(id: params[:id])
    RideLaterRequestHandler.ride_later_request_created(@ride_later_request)
    # redirect, render, or whatever depending on whether you want this 
    # to be AJAXy or regular HTML.
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: Let me try this. Instead of creating a controller I can define that method in the existing controller right ? I already have a controller called **admin_reports** in which I am listing the records of `RideLaterRequest` model. So I can add the method you mentioned there itself right ?

Comment: Sure. I was just riffing. TBH, if I were you, I would try to stay RESTful about the whole thing and create a `RideLaterRequestNotificationsController` and use the `create` action to do your thing. But, hey, whatever floats your boat.